# Idle timeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a problem with the code below and can't figure out why it's not working.
Basically when the timer function kicks in (user is idle for 30 minutes) I would like it to check to see if my child windows are open and if so close them.
If the window named "interpwindow" is open and not "child" it will close "interpwindow" and load my login page (this is good). 
If both "interpwindow" and "child" are open it will also do what I expect. 
If "child" is open but not "interpwindow", it closes "child" but does not load the login page.
It neither "child" or "interpwindow" are open it will not go to my login page.

Any ideas?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
   //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});
function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 29) 
    { // 30 minutes
            if(child)
            { 
         child.close();
             }
    if(interpwindow)
             {
         interpwindow.close();
             }
        location.href = "Login.html";
       }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please read the popup that says what a tag is about.  Python-IDLE has nothing to do with javascript and program idling.

Comment: Do you have anything that happens when a window closes?  Like a window.onbeforeunload or window.onunload?

Comment: No. Just the code above.